# Problem with Django {% extends %} templating

Tags: python, django

I am building a webapp with Django and Python 3.7 and I'm really confused by this simple thing:

[image]

These are my templates. They are all in the same directory.
When I try to call {% extends 'store.html' %} , I get `TemplateDoesNotExist at /publicaciones/` and it points to `store.html`. This is in `publicaciones.html`. Here's the template:
***publicaciones.html:***

```
{% extends "store.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style_reset-pass.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Publicaciones</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> 
        {% block content %}
        {% for item in items %}
            {{ item|crispy }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?
Please ask if you need any other code. I'll answer immediately.

Comment: It should be `{% extends "store/store.html" %}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `{% extends "store/store.html" %}`

You have path as `templates/store/store.html`

Answer (score 4):

You refer to the super template just like you refer to a template in the view for example. In case you thus should refer to it as `"store/store.html"`:

```
{% extends "store/store.html" %}
```

Note that if you extend a template, you can only fill in the [**`{% block … %}…{% endblock %}`** template blocks [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#block), so you can not just write an entire html file, that would be rather non-sensical, since otherwise there is no reason to inherit the template.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the point @baldr made, make sure you specify the template folder in your `settings.py` file (properly): like `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]` in the `TEMPLATES` section